# How can I write a code that fulfill all the requirements for this set?

Tags: python, set

The objective of this task is to find the set X that fulfill all of the following requirements:

> 1. X = {x | x ∈ Z and x > 0}.
> 2. A = {(x mod 2) | x ∈ X}
>
> B = {y |sqrt(y) ∈ X}
>
> C = {sqrt(z) | z ∈ (X ∩ B)}
>
> D = {w^2| w ∈ C}
>
> 3. 0 < |X|.
> 4. |X| ∈ X.
> 5. |A|  *(not element in)* X.
> 6. sum(X) ∈ B.
> 7. sum(X ∩ B) 6 *(not element in)* B.
> 8. sum(C ∪ D) ∈ X.

So this is the problem I'm trying to solve.

I've tried solving this by hand and found that X = {6, 36, 31, 33, 11, 4} is a set that fits the requirements. I've written a code in Python as well but my code isn't working. I'm not getting any error messages, it just won't output a set that fulfill the requirements. This is the code I've written in Python:

```
import random
import math

def check(t):

    X1 = t
    X = set([x for x in X1 if x>0])
    A = set([x%2 for x in X]) - set([0])
    print "A= ", "\t", A
    B = set([math.pow(y,2) for y in X ])
    print "B= ", "\t", B
    C = set([math.pow(z, 0.5) for z in X.intersection(B)])
    print "C= ", "\t", C
    D = set([math.pow(w, 2) for w in C])
    print "D= ", "\t", D, "\n"

    #                 (iii)
    if len(X) >0:
        print "iii.\t The cardinality of X bigger than 0." 

    #                 (iv)
    if len(X) in X:
        print "iv.\t\t The cardinality of X is element in X" 

    #                  (v)
    if len(A) not in X:
        print "v.\t\t Cardinality of A is not element in X."

    #                  (vi)
    if sum(X) in B:
        print "vi.\t\t Sum of X is element in B."

    #   (vii)
    if sum(X) and sum(B) not in X:
        print "vii.\t Sum of X and B is not element in B"

    #        (viii)
    if sum(C) in X or sum(D) in X:
        print "viii.\t Sum of C exits in X."


    if len(X)>0 and len(X) in X and len(A) not in X and sum(X) in B and sum(X) not in B and sum(B) not in B and sum(C) in X or sum(D) in X:
        print "Set X is ","\t\t ", X
        print "Fits the requirements."
       # print "A = ", A
    else:
        print "Does not fit the requirements."



def guess():
    b = 20
    genSet = random.sample( range(2,b), 6 )
    t = set(genSet)
    print "---------------"
    print "Generated set is: ", t
    return check(t)



counter=1
while not guess():

    print "try nr: ", teller
    counter+=1
```

As you may notice I've just assumed the set to be of length=6, but that's just for now as I'm trying to get the code to work. And my range of random number isn't that big either for the same reason.

I've also written some if/else-statements in between to check whether the requirements are fulfillled or not.

Comment: According to your code, `A` can only ever be {} or {1}, and so have cardinality 0 or 1, neither of which is an element of the set `X` you say fits the requirements.

Comment: Ok, but what do I need to change in order to make the code work?

Comment: IMO this isn't really a problem for such a Monte Carlo approach because of the sheer number of sets you would need to randomly select before you find one that meets the requirements. I would work it out with pen and paper, and failing that ask the folk at math.stackexchange.

Comment: Well, it's in fact my assignment to do this via programming, Python to be more specific. So that's why I need help.

Comment: I'm not sure what answer is expected here. "Find the set X" but `X` is defined in the question (`X = {x | x ∈ Z and x > 0}`). (Assuming [Z is the integers](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Z.html), if not what is it?)

Comment: You're supposed to find a set `X`(capital letter) elements consisting of x (small lettter).

Answer (score 0):

Ignore my comments: don't know what I was thinking. Simply set

```
A = set([x%2 for x in X])
```

and make sure you `return` something from your function `check`:

```
    ...
    print "Fits the requirements."
    # print "A = ", A
    return True
else:
    print "Does not fit the requirements."
    return False
...
```

And you need to get the logic right in your comparison (the long `if` statement):

```
import random
import math

def check(t):

    X1 = t
    X = set([x for x in X1 if x>0])
    A = set([x%2 for x in X])
    print "A= ", "\t", A
    B = set([math.pow(y,2) for y in X ])
    print "B= ", "\t", B
    C = set([math.pow(z, 0.5) for z in X.intersection(B)])
    print "C= ", "\t", C
    D = set([math.pow(w, 2) for w in C])
    print "D= ", "\t", D, "\n"

    #                 (iii)
    if len(X) >0:
        print "iii.\t The cardinality of X bigger than 0." 

    #                 (iv)
    if len(X) in X:
        print "iv.\t\t The cardinality of X is element in X" 

    #                  (v)
    if len(A) not in X:
        print "v.\t\t Cardinality of A is not element in X."

    #                  (vi)
    print '(vi)', sum(X), B
    if sum(X) in B:
        print "vi.\t\t Sum of X is element in B."

    #   (vii)
    if sum(X) and sum(B) not in X:
        print "vii.\t Sum of X and B is not element in B"

    #        (viii)
    if sum(C) in X or sum(D) in X:
        print "viii.\t Sum of C exits in X."


    if len(X)>0 and len(X) in X and len(A) not in X and sum(X) in B and sum(X.intersection(B)) not in B and sum(C.union(D)) in X:
        print "Set X is ","\t\t ", X
        print "Fits the requirements."
       # print "A = ", A
        return True
    else:
        print "Does not fit the requirements."
        return False



def guess():
    b = 20
    genSet = random.sample( range(1,b), 6 )
    t = set(genSet)
    print "---------------"
    print "Generated set is: ", t
    return check(t)
```

With these edits, one solution appears to be `{1, 3, 4, 6, 9, 13}`.

Comment: Why would I need to return `True`?

Comment: Ah, I see why now. I would need that so my guess()-function know when to stop. But I still don't get a set that fulfill the requirements..?

Comment: The only requirement there seem to be a problem with is the one about sum(X) = B. For some reason Python thinks the if/else reason is fulfilled even though the statement sum(X) ∈ B is not fulfilled. Do you have any idea of why?

Comment: The problem you're seeing there is due to your `if len(X)>0 and` statement. Be careful about the precedence: this whole expression is `True`  if `sum(D) in X`. Use parentheses.

Comment: So you mean like this:
`if (len(X)>0) and (len(X) in X) and (len(A) not in X) and (sum(X) in B) and (sum(X) not in B) and (sum(B) not in B) and (sum(C) in X) or (sum(D) in X):`?
Still doesn't solve the problem..

Comment: The application finish even though neither requirement 4. |X| ∈ X or requirement 6. sum(X) ∈ B is fulfilled.

Comment: Do you have any idea of how to solve these problems?

Comment: I don't know how to solve your assignment, but I do  know that your logic in this `if` statement doesn't match the requirements. At a quick look, you need something more like `if len(X)>0 and len(X) in X and len(A) not in X and sum(X) in B and sum(X.intersection(B)) not in B and sum(C.union(D) in X:`

Comment: Why do you think that I have to define the intersection and union inside the condition when I've already defined it as a set at the beginning?
Writing the if statement as you suggested just makes the loop continue..

Comment: You need these because those are requirements 7 and 8. You _define_ `C` with an intesection, but test 8 involves the union of this set with `D`. See edits