# Python, check if sets check out

Tags: python, performance, loops, math, set

I have made the function, but I need to make a guess so it will run through the function and check if it fits, if not, start over again with new numbers.

If I find a set that works, the loop should break, the problem is that I am new to python and math programming.

```
def checkStuff(X):
    ok = True
    #i.
    if(min(X) <= 0):
        ok = False

    #ii.A
    A = set()
    for x in X:
        A.add(x % 2)

    #ii.B
    B = set()
    for y in X:
        B.add(y**2)

    #ii.C
    C = set()
    for z in X & B:
        C.add(z**0.5)

    #ii.D
    D = set()
    for w in C:
        D.add(w**2)

    #iii.
    if(len(X)<=0):
        ok = False

    #iv.
    if(len(X) not in X):
        ok = False

    #v.
    if len(A) in X:
        ok = False

    #vi.
    if sum(X) not in B:
        ok = False

    #vii.
    if sum(X&B) in B:
        ok = False

    #viii.
    if sum(C.union(D)) not in X:
        ok = False

    return ok
```

Comment: ...What is the problem? I have no idea what you are attempting. Give us context!

Comment: What are you asking? how to loop through? how to break the loop? how to generate the set?

Comment: find the set X that fulfill all of the following
requirements. The function i have writen does that, but i need to make a loop that guesses the set over and over again, kinda bruteforce it, until i have a set that fits.

Comment: if i do like 

s = {1,2,3,4}
print checkStuff(s) 

i will test if s fits the requirments

Comment: Can you rather edit your question and state "the requirements" clear in english instead of writing a code and not stating the problem? By the way `#iv.` and `#v.` are contradicting each other. If you want to break when you find the set that works, you should start by setting the initial value of `ok` to `False` and if your test pass it should set the value to `ok = True`, you dont need a loop. You need else if statements instead of if statements to act as a `break` equivalent of loops. Else if statement is `elif` in python.

Comment: Since SO is now in the business of doing homework, why not just copy your colleague's corrected answer down at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28440271/how-can-i-write-a-code-that-fulfill-all-the-requirements-for-this-set/28442792#28442792

Answer (score 0):

without giving you the exact code, try looking at the while loop and the [random function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html)

Comment: im struggeling with how i should write the while loop, since i dont know how long the set is or anything.

Comment: You have started right by building the function first. Now build the next step. a set generator for a fixed size set. when you get that working you have two other tasks. 1) make it loop and 2) add a variable to modify the size of the generated set

Comment: Ok, tbh im all new to python, and its my first task this semester, am not sure how i should move forward. But will try my best, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your function can be simplified and optimized, returning as soon as possible, avoiding further computations... for compactness I used set comprehensions instead of your loops

```
def checkStuff(X):

    if(min(X) <= 0):     return False
    if(len(X)<=0):       return False
    if(len(X) not in X): return False

    A = {x % 2 for x in X}
    if len(A) in X:      return False

    B = {x**2 for x in X}
    if sum(X) not in B:  return False
    if sum(X&B) in B:    return False

    C = {xb**0.5 for xb in X&B}
    D = {c**2 for c in C}
    if sum(C.union(D)) not in X: return False

    return True
```

Assuming that you have a function that returns a list of trial sets or, possibly better, `yield`s a new trial set for each loop,  and that you want to use ONLY the first `X` that matches your conditions, then you can write your stuff like this

```
for X in generate_trial_sets():
    if checkStuff(X):
        do_stuff(X)
        break
else:
    print("No X was generated matching the criteria")

...
```

Note that the `else` clause is aligned correctly, because Python has a [`for ... else ..`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) control flow construct.

#### Blind Attempt at a `generate_trial_sets` Function

Given that each `X` is a set of numbers (integers? reals? complex numbers? who knows? you, but you didn't care to tell...) and that we don't know how many numbers you want in the set, and also that you want to stop the iteration somehow, I'd write

```
def generate_trial_sets(nmin=1,   nmax=5,
                        xmin=0.0, xmax=10.0, iterations=10):
    from random import randint
    for _ in range(iterations):
        n = randint(nmin,nmax+1)
        x = {n}
        for i in range(1,n):
            x.add((xmax-xmin)*random()+xmin)
        yield x
```

When you call it like

```
for X in generate_trial_sets():
```

without modifying the default args, you get back 10 sets of length comprised between 1 and 5, with real values comprised between 0 and 10 (one of the values is equal to the length, so one of your tests is automatically fulfilled).

To use different parameters, specify them at the invocation:

```
for X in generate_trial_sets(nmin=6,nmax=6,xmax=100.0,iterations=200):
```

This is not a solution of your problem but if you understand the logic you'll get started in the right direction or, at least, I hope so...

Comment: hmmmm im not getting this.

Comment: Have you a specific question that I can address, or is it the whole of it...?

Comment: I understand your checkstuff, but the genereate X is where im falling off. i need to do_stuff function aswell dont i ?